# Trying to send an email in PHP only after the submit button is pressed and the form is valid

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am new to PHP and currently getting back to HTML. I have made a form and have the data sent and validated by PHP but I am trying to send the email to myself only after the data had been validated and is correct. Currently if the page is loaded I think it send an email and it will send whenever I hit submit without the data being correct.

Here is where I validate the data:

```
<?php
  //Set main variables for the data.
  $fname = $lname = $email = $subject = $website = $likedsite = $findoption = $comments = "";

  //Set the empty error variables.
  $fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $subjectErr = $commentsErr = $websiteErr = $findoptionErr = "";

  //Check to see if the form was submitted.
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
  {
    //Check the 'First Name' field.
    if (empty($_POST["fname"]))
    {
      $fnameErr = "First Name is Required.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $fname = validate_info($_POST["fname"]);
    }

    //Check the 'Last Name' field.
    if (empty($_POST["lname"]))
    {
      $lnameErr = "Last Name is Required.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $lname = validate_info($_POST["lname"]);
    }

    //Check the 'E-Mail' field.
    if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
      $emailErr = "E-Mail is Required.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $email = validate_info($_POST["email"]);
      //Check if valid email.
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
      {
        $emailErr = "Invalid E-Mail Format.";
      }
    }

    //Check the 'Subject' field.
    if (empty($_POST["subject"]))
    {
      $subjectErr = "Subject is Required.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $subject = validate_info($_POST["subject"]);
    }

    //Check the 'Website' field.
    if (empty($_POST["siteurl"]))
    {
      $website = "";
    } 
    else
    {
      $website = validate_info($_POST["siteurl"]);
      //Check if valid URL.
      if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website))
      {
        $websiteErr = "Invalid URL.";
      }
    }

    //Check the 'How Did You Find Us' options.
    if (empty($_POST["howfind"]))
    {
      $findoptionErr = "Please Pick One.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $findoption = validate_info($_POST["howfind"]);
    }

    //Check the comment box.
    if (empty($_POST["questioncomments"]))
    {
      $commentsErr = "Questions/Comments are Required.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $comments = validate_info($_POST["questioncomments"]);
    }

    //Pass any un-required data.
    $likedsite = validate_info($_POST["likedsite"]);
  }

  function validate_info($data)
  {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }
?>
```

Sorry its a little lengthy.

Here is where I try to send the email. I have tried two different attempts and both have the same result.

```
    <?php
if (!empty($fnameErr) || !empty($lnameErr) || !empty($subjectErr) || !empty($emailErr) || !empty($commentErr) || !empty($websiteErr) || !empty($findoptionErr))
{
  echo "Sent!!";
}else
{
  echo"Not Sent!!";
}
  //Make the message.
  $message =
  "
  First Name: $fname.\n
  Last Name: $lname.\n
  Website: $website\n
  Did They Like the Site? $likedsite.\n
  How They Found Us. $findoption.\n
  Question/Comments:\n
  $comments.
  ";
  $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
  $headers = "From: $email";

  mail("me@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Once again sorry for the length. Thanks in advance also sorry if this is a double question or not described enough I am also new to stack overflow.

Comment: Replace || by && so it will count as 'and' instear of 'or'

Comment: I did just try that and it worked saying "Not Sent". When I filled the form out fully and correctly with no errors it did not change to "Sent".

Comment: My bad, i thought you were using the input instead of error vars ahah , try to replace || by && and remove ! In front of each , so if they are all empty(no error) it should sent.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that now. Kinda my fault too. I totally should've noticed that.

Comment: @TheGamingMann, I post answer with some code solution. Once every validation message variable are empty then only website send mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
<?php
  //Set main variables for the data.
  $fname = $lname = $email = $subject = $website = $likedsite = $findoption = $comments = "";

  //Set the empty error variables.
  $fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $subjectErr = $commentsErr = $websiteErr = $findoptionErr = "";

  //Initialize variable used to identify form is valid OR not. 
  $formValid = true;

  //Check to see if the form was submitted.
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
  {
    //Check the 'First Name' field.
    if (empty($_POST["fname"]))
    {
      $formValid = false;//Form not validate
      $fnameErr = "First Name is Required.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $fname = validate_info($_POST["fname"]);
    }

    //Check the 'Last Name' field.
    if (empty($_POST["lname"]))
    {
      $formValid = false;//Form not validate
      $lnameErr = "Last Name is Required.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $lname = validate_info($_POST["lname"]);
    }

    //Check the 'E-Mail' field.
    if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
      $formValid = false;//Form not validate
      $emailErr = "E-Mail is Required.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $email = validate_info($_POST["email"]);
      //Check if valid email.
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
      {
        $formValid = false;//Form not validate
        $emailErr = "Invalid E-Mail Format.";
      }
    }

    //Check the 'Subject' field.
    if (empty($_POST["subject"]))
    {
      $formValid = false;//Form not validate
      $subjectErr = "Subject is Required.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $subject = validate_info($_POST["subject"]);
    }

    //Check the 'Website' field.
    if (empty($_POST["siteurl"]))
    {
      $website = "";
    } 
    else
    {
      $website = validate_info($_POST["siteurl"]);
      //Check if valid URL.
      if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website))
      {
        $formValid = false;//Form not validate
        $websiteErr = "Invalid URL.";
      }
    }

    //Check the 'How Did You Find Us' options.
    if (empty($_POST["howfind"]))
    {
      $formValid = false;//Form not validate
      $findoptionErr = "Please Pick One.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $findoption = validate_info($_POST["howfind"]);
    }

    //Check the comment box.
    if (empty($_POST["questioncomments"]))
    {
      $formValid = false;//Form not validate
      $commentsErr = "Questions/Comments are Required.";
    } 
    else
    {
      $comments = validate_info($_POST["questioncomments"]);
    }

    //Pass any un-required data.
    $likedsite = validate_info($_POST["likedsite"]);
  }


  //If every variable value set, send mail OR display error...
  if (!$formValid){
     echo"Form not validate...";

  } 
  else {
      //Make the message.
      $message =
      "
      First Name: $fname.\n
      Last Name: $lname.\n
      Website: $website\n
      Did They Like the Site? $likedsite.\n
      How They Found Us. $findoption.\n
      Question/Comments:\n
      $comments.
      ";
      $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
      $headers = "From: $email";

      mail("me@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);


      if($sendMail){
        echo "Mail Sent!!";
      }
      else {
        echo "Mail Not Sent!!";
      }
  }

  function validate_info($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }
?>
```

I edit my answer as per some change. Now this code only allow send mail if form required fields are not empty and all fields value are valid as per your validation.

Let me know if there is any concern.!

Comment: Tired that and it keeps sending blank emails. It did work once but wouldn't send the complete form not its sends it anytime I hit submit.

Comment: From your question, you initialized every error message variable with blank. Also you apply conditional check with `IF` statement. So there is no issue with mine code. Let me know what does your `validate_info()` here?

Comment: I edit my answer with full code. Please check and let me know if it not perfect.

Comment: That does work. My only problem now is for some reason it will not send me an email with the data when it says sent. Also it still sends a blank form when the page is opened. I think I can solve the page open with making it a simple redirect. Thanks so much for you help so far.

Comment: So I just did some more testing and the variables are being passed as they can be echoed correctly. There must be an error in the mail() function. I'll keep looking and keep you posted. Thanks again.

Comment: I personally suggest you to use PHPMailer(http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). This handles errors nicely, also a good script to use for sending mail via SMTP

Comment: Thanks again. I was just an idiot the other and forgot to read. I have to make an email account on the host I'm using to send them with the mail function... Sorry for causing trouble. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing lengthy conditions.

1. Assign all error messages to a single variable and append errors to it (`$errorMsg`). You can avoid lengthy if else ladder by doing this.
2. Change `empty($_POST["email"])` to `!isset($_POST["email"])` - In all statements.

Then update the condition to following,

```
<?php
if($errorMsg == ''){
  //Make the message.
  $message ="
  First Name: ".$fname.".\n
  Last Name: ".$lname."\n
  Website: ".$website."\n
  Did They Like the Site? ".$likedsite."\n
  How They Found Us. ".$findoption."\n
  Question/Comments:\n
  ".$comments." ";
  $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
  $headers = "From: $email";
  mail("me@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
}else{
  // Show $errorMsg
}
?>
```

Make it simple, I hope this helps.

Comment: I would do that but would I still be able to echo the error beside the input field that caused it? Currently I echo the error back to the html form.                                                                                                       First Name:
        <input name="fname" type="text" value="<?php echo $fname;?>"/>
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>

Comment: Current issue is, you are sending mail outside condition. Wrap it inside condition.

Comment: So should I make a variable for it or stick it inside an if statement?

Comment: Send mail from inside the if statement. I prefer variable method (since it is the standard way). Try to reduce lines in your code. It's just a best practice.

Comment: What I tried to do was what AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd posted. I changed it up a little and I get a blank email when I open the page then I go to submit the completed form and it echos sent. I have yet to receive the email with the completed form. I have it like if($sendMail) {echo "Sent";}else{echo "Not Sent";}

Answer (score 0):

from what i was able to conceive, u are

1. trying to apply 'OR' in if condition- should be changed to AND i.e. change || to &&
2. you are checking for not empty error variables... which should be changed to verify if they all are empty  or not.

`if (empty($fnameErr) && empty($lnameErr) && empty($subjectErr) && empty($emailErr) && empty($commentErr) && empty($websiteErr) && empty($findoptionErr))
    {
    echo "sent";
    }`